# JButton font appears different on different pc's

Tags: java, fonts, jbutton

I make a .exe file and send it to my friend. It contains a jbutton with a cool font on it that does some things. In my pc, the font appears normal but on his pc its doesn't show, showing the default that is not so cool. Why is that so? The font I use is:

```
Font f1 = new Font("Quartz MS", Font.PLAIN, 40);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the font installed on pc to be able to show it. So try sending the font to your friend alogn with your app.